# Are mathematics and philosophy in contradiction here?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-logic

[image: My proposition & approach towards contradiction]

Have I committed any mistake?
Would you please enlighten me about the validity of this derivation?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Well there's no universal set. That's one problem.

Comment: But here my universal set is evidently the set 'everything' which reflects the fact that anything existing in this creation is within it. Isn't it so?

Comment: There's an equivocation on "nothing." The null set is simply a set with no members; it does not have the same philosophical meaning as you are intending when you use the word in a statement like "nothing is (im)possible."

Comment: Would you please provide a clarified analysis of your view point?

Comment: I made an edit to clarify the question. You may roll this back or continue editing. You can see the versions by clicking on the "edited" link above. I think you raised a good question.

Comment: Your error is in the second premise: "Nothing is an element of Everything". This is simply FALSE, or better : non-sense.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Apparently it is so. Perhaps I am unable to explain the sense of that line until & unless you yourself try to realise it from a logistic mathematical point of view.

Comment: There is not 'set of everything' that contains everything existing, since the 'set of everything' is not in it and therefore does not exist. .

Comment: @PeterJ In the same manner, can't we say that the universal set U in mathematics doesn't exist? It's evident from argument that universal set can't contain the set itself (hypothetical point of view)

Comment: @SULAGNABARAT - I'm no mathematician but I'd say you're right. The 'set of all sets' is an impossible object. This is an utterly vital issue in metaphysics.

Answer (score 6):

You have an ambiguity between 'Nothing' as an object and 'Nothing' as a quantifier. When you say "Nothing is possible", you're talking about an object, in this case the empty set. But when you say "Nothing is impossible", you're not talking about an object, but rather you're quantifying over everything, saying that whatever is in there is possible.

This is a [fallacy of ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation) (also called 'equivocation').

Comment: I haven't claimed that 'nothing is possible rather it has been deduced that 'nothing is 'also' possible; in a sense of partial negativity. When the term 'also' is added, 'nothing', definitely contained within 'everything' (highlighting occurrence or non-occurence) remains in its objective form .

Comment: @SULAGNABARAT Right, 'nothing' is in its objective form in this statement, but it is used as a quantifier in the other, thus the ambiguity.

Comment: @SULAGNABARAT, you're using scare quotes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes) to try to extrapolate your point, but those scare quotes are exactly what's causing you to equivocate.

Comment: I think I'm getting a bit of your point right now but haven't made it out completely. Where lies the utilization of introducing the word 'also'?                                                      Okay, I'm trying my best to analyze it more explicitly. Thanks a lot for helping:)

Comment: @SULAGNABARAT 'Also' does not add any logical content -- it just makes it easier to see that you're talking about an object. Which is ok. But you're not talking about that object when you say "Nothing is impossible." Same word but different meanings. Another example: "Everything takes up a lot of space" is also ambiguous in the same way. On one reading it means that the totality of things takes up a lot of space (true), on another it says that every single object does (false).

Comment: Isn't there any difference between "Nothing is possible" & "Nothing is also possible"?

Comment: Lewis Carroll was fond of playing off this ambiguity. This from Alice Through the Looking Glass. "Who did you pass on the road?" the King went on. "Nobody," said the Messenger. "Quite right," said the King: "this young lady saw him too. So of course Nobody walks slower than you." "I do my best," the Messenger said in a sullen tone. "I'm sure nobody walks much faster than I do!" "He can't do that," said the King, "or else he'd have been here first."

Answer (score 2):

The null set would be a *subset* of any other set we might have. However, the null set need not be an *element* of any set we might have.

Let S be the set of interest. By assumption every element in S is possible. There is no element of S that is not possible. The null set, however, is not an element of S.  Rather the null set is a subset of S.

So, let x be an element of the null set. (There aren't any elements of the null set, but we can assume there are.) Then x would also be an element of S because the null set is a subset of S. That means that x is an element of S and so x is possible.  This argument does not mean that the null set itself is possible or impossible because the null set itself is not an element of S.

Here is a reference noting that the null set is a subset of any set but not an element of any set: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Empty_Set_is_Subset_of_All_Sets

Comment: I think I know what you intend to say, but there are sets that have the null set as an element, and thus are counterexamples to "the null set ... is not an element of any set"

Comment: @Hurkyl I made an edit. I hope this covered the issue you raised: "the null set need not be an element of any set we might have".